# ImportError: cant import name nn from neat

Tags: python

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import itertools
import os

from neat import nn, population, statistics

with open('data.csv', 'rU') as f:  #opens PW file

    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(list(rec) for rec in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')) #reads csv into a list of lists
    f.close() #close the csv

def eval_fitness(genomes):

    fitness = 0
    something = 0
    best_fitness = -99999
    for g in genomes:
        fitness = 0
        net = nn.create_feed_forward_phenotype(g)
```

Comment: and your question is what?

Comment: No clear question, need to improve your formating...

Comment: What problem/error are you seeing? If you don't add this the question is likely to end up being closed

Comment: I think problem is in quesiton's title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install:

```
pip install neat-python==0.8
```

i assume u only installed

```
pip install neat
```

Comment: I have already installed neat then too its showing "ImportError: Cant import name 'nn' "

Comment: I did same and i can import nn now . Try installing both `neat` and than `near-python==0.8`

Comment: or try this . may be have dependency : `pip install scipy neat-python==0.8 argparse`